# what kind of password hashing algorithm is used by asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, sql-server, hash, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am using code first approach for an ASP.NET mvc 5. I am connecting my database with a android application against the same website. now I have a problem , to generate the same Hash Password that I am generating using ASP.NET mvc , the default size of hash password is 68 characters but SHA256 has 64 , then what can be the right way , kindly guide

Comment: There is no default hashing algorithm for mvc5. The answer depends on what security framework you are using, maybe you meant asp.net-identity2 ?

Comment: yes its asp.net identity2

Comment: I want to generate same kind of hashPassword in java so that it may never be a conflict when a user who made account on android and tries to access via website may feel any error